# How to create a commercial library with template using in C++?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm a noob in C++ meta programming and I understand that I must place implementation of class in header file for convention. But when you want to purchase an package you need to separate the header and the implementation.

Now, Is there a way to do this?

Note: I know about 'export' keyword and read this [page](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13)!

Comment: Put the "implementation" in header files `*.h` (or in `*.tcc` files `# include`-d from `*.h`).

Comment: "But when you want to purchase an package you need to separate the header and the implementation" -- why is that?  And forget about `export` it's only been implemented  once or twice in a compiler, and moving forward it's gone. It's been pulled from the C++11 standard (at the request of the one company that implemented it).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Because charging money for proprietary source code that the buyer can open in Notepad would seem to defeat the object.

Comment: L-GPL? Save the cloak and dagger stuff?

Comment: Ok, can you explain L-GPL some more for this case?

Comment: What about using obfuscators ? I'm not sure if they handle header files like implementation ones.

Comment: @DonReba: Er, ["defeat the object" is just fine](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/object_3) ([yes, even in the offshoot language known as "American English"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/object_2)). Probably not in Spanish, though. Thank you.

Comment: Since you've read that page I take it that explicitly specifying the types allowed with the template is not acceptable. Since nobody supports exported templates, any time the template is instantiated the full definition must be visible. So you don't really have a choice but to make the template definition available. If you're concerned about protecting your IP just include copyright notices in your headers and make sure your the license you sell to your customers prohibits them from doing with it the things you don't want them to do. If you don't care about the IP then don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several vendors providing general templates for purchase (BTW, I assume you want to *sell* the template code rather than *purchase* it) and they simply ship the source. The license agreement states that you can't distribute or modify the code. Done.

If that's not good enough for your needs here are a few things you can do:

- Factor code into components with minimal dependency on template arguments. This may yield parts of the code you can put into a readily compiled object because they don't depend on template arguments or you can preinstantiate the code.
- Obfuscating the code may be one way to go. In this context it is worth noting that a reason given for the absense of an "Obfuscated C++ Contest" by Steve Clamage was: "That would be like shooting fish in a barrel."
- Create a service where customers upload the class declarations needed for template instantiation and get back the compiled instantiation. Of course, if you don't trust the customers they have no reason to assume that you might be trustworthy.
- Wait for the next revision of the standard which hopefully has some sort of *module* support helping with this issue. I wouldn't bet too high on this, however.

Personally, I wouldn't bother: from feedback I get back on my code it seems that despite documentation and explanations nobody is prepared to touch it. I think it is rather readable..,

Comment: +1 for answer ,I can do my job without **template**, but this is a good feature of language and I prefer to use this feature.

Comment: @softghost: you can use templates for your _implementation_ without problems: no need to put anything into the header. If you can expose the interface without templates you are all sorted. Alternatively, you may provide a "nice" interface externally using templates but delegate to a template-free interface, i.e. you would expose a thin wrapper in the header file but have the proprietary code tagged away. If your interface and implementation need templates there isn't much you can do beyond providing the source, obfuscation, or on-demand compilation.

Answer (score 3):

No, not really. Templates must be visible at compile-time so, if your users are to instantiate templates themselves, they need the definitions.

You'll just have to explicitly instantiate for as many template-parameter-list combinations as you feel you'll need, and hope that your users don't need any more.

Think of templates as something that helps you inside a single project. This inherent limitation means that they are not appropriate as a "I can provide my library for the user to specialise with any type they want" mechanism.

Comment: Assume we have a stack and we want to purchase, what can I do?

Comment: @softghost: Well, you haven't stated any actual requirements, so it's difficult to say what you need to do with templates.

Comment: I want to use template programming but I don't want anyone see my source code.

Comment: @softghost: You might as well have just said "I want to be rich but I don't want to do any work". It's not a real requirement: it's a pipe dream. Instead explain specifically why you feel you need your users to be able to instantiate your templates? And/or why you need templates? "I want to use template programming" is not a technical requirement, nor is it meaningful in any context without a rationale.

Comment: Don't interpret my statement like this, there are many good features are listed for **template**. I don't want to demonstrate that. But with current state of structure you can't to publish the code without source code when using template.

Comment: @softghost: Correct. That's why I'm trying to extract from you the reason that you want to "use template", other than just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can obfuscate your code, you can separate the implementation in a `impl` file and include it in the header, but it **must** be visible to the compiler.

However, if there's a way you can restrict how many actual specializations are used, you can move specialized implementations in a `cpp` file, keep the declaration in the header, and it would still work:

#### header.h

```
template<typename X>
void foo(X x);

template<>
void foo<int>(int x);
```

#### impl1.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

template<>
void foo<int>(int x)
{
}
```

#### impl2.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

foo(1); //works
```

Also, I don't think you should worry about this. Because they are generic, I don't think templates can have that much of an important logic inside of them. Take a look at the standard ones - `vector`, `list` - sure, they would take some time to write from scratch, but there's no real commercial secret in there.

Comment: No. 14.7.3p6: If a template, a member template or the member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that
specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instan-
tiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

Comment: @aschepler I didn't know that. Just MSVS being overly-permissive again. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't exactly a fault with MSVC either, since allowing it to "work" is a valid behavior for an ill-formed program with "no diagnostic required".  For anybody just reading this now: it's fixed now because the explicit specialization is declared in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

*templatelib.h*

```
template<typename T> void foo();
```

*templatelib.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "templatelib.h"

template<typename T> void foo() {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << '\n';
}

template void foo<int>(); // explicitly instantiate template for this type
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "templatelib.h"

int main() {
    foo<int>(); // Okay
    foo<double>(); // error
}
```